# Edit history bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

When you, as OP, edit a question/answer in the first minutes after posting, the edit will not be registered in the edit history

Steps to reproduce :

- Post a question/answer
- Edit it, while leaving the edit summary blank

Expected result :

Like in all SE sites I have contributed to, such edits are taken into the edit history even after such little period of time

Happening :

The question/answer will be edited, but the edit history is not populated and there will not be a `edited <date>` message. Such behavior ends after ~30min where all edits made after will join the edit history

Can reproduce on Firefox 101, Chrome 102 on all platforms (Mobile and Desktop)

**EDIT:** I have verified that the bug is also here in Meta (I changed `edit reason` to `edit summary`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember I have seen it called the grace period and it is common on several or all Stack Exchange sites. See [Editing FAQ on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work/21789#21789) for more information.

So I would not call it a bug but a feature which was unknown to you till now.

It is not (normally) 30 minutes but more like 5 minutes.

I edited this answer after 'one' minute, not edit message.
I edited after two minutes with a reason and it did get an edit message.

But the next edit without a reason did not change the edited message.

Comment: Would that be likely to be site-specific? I am pretty sure AskUbuntu for ex. doesn't have such thing (although I might be mistaken)

Comment: Sometimes sites can use or not use some network features, I am not sure whether this is one of those or not. I just assume that it is the same on all sites, edit within a few (5?) minutes and it does not get the marker. (I often do not add a reason as it is mostly spelling errors I did catch after posting.)

Comment: Got it, thanks @Willeke